# Creating a Gradle plugin with a dependency on another (external) plugin

Tags: gradle

I want to create a plugin that automatically applies other (external plugins). This requires setting the buildscript dependency for the plugin before I call "apply plugin". However it seems like I can't add buildscript dependencies in a plugin or I get:
 **You can't change a configuration which is not in unresolved state!**

Is there a solution to this ?

My sample (non-working) code:

```
import org.gradle.api.Project
import org.gradle.api.Plugin
class SamplePlugin implements Plugin<Project>{
  void apply(Project project) {

    project.buildscript.dependencies.add("classpath","net.sourceforge.cobertura:cobertura:1.9.4.1");

    project.configure(project){         
      apply plugin: 'cobertura' 
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The way to go about this is to publish a pom.xml or ivy.xml along with the plugin Jar that describes the plugin's dependencies. Alternatively, you can write a script plugin that declares its dependencies in a `buildscript {}` section. A script plugin is simply a reusable build script that gets applied with `apply from: ...`.

Comment: In case anyone is interested in how this is done exactly: you have to extend the default POM in your MavenPublication. Netflix's Nebula plugins are a great source for examples: https://github.com/nebula-plugins/nebula-publishing-plugin/blob/master/src%2Fmain%2Fgroovy%2Fnebula%2Fplugin%2Fpublishing%2Fmaven%2FMavenJavaPublishingPlugin.groovy

Comment: Latest link to Nebula publish Plugin, in case anyone visits this page. https://github.com/nebula-plugins/nebula-publishing-plugin/blob/master/src/main/groovy/nebula/plugin/publishing/maven/MavenPublishPlugin.groovy

Comment: Any guidance on this in 2019? I need to do same thing as OP, but i find this answer cryptic / undocumented. I don't see the nebula plugin using this pattern.